# Question regarding the order of a proper subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How would you find the smallest (integer) $n$ such that the group of integers modulo $n$ has a proper subgroup of a prescribed order order?

Otherwise stated: What is the smallest integer $n$ such that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ has a proper subgroup of order $a$?

Comment: I think you mean "prescribed order", rather than "arbitrary order".

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It's unclear as it is.

Comment: I rephrased it in the main question

Comment: Take $\mathbb{Z}_{2a}$. It has the subgroup $2\mathbb{Z}_{2a}$ which has order $a$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $m$ has been given and we want to find the smallest $n$ such that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ has a subgroup of order $m$.

Suppose that $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is a group with a subgroup of order $m$, then by the Lagrange theorem, $m \mid n$ but since it has to be a proper subgroup, $n \geq 2m$.

Take $n=2m$ and consider the subgroup $2\mathbb{Z}_{2m}$. It has order $m$ and therefore, $\mathbb{Z}_{2m}$ works and it's optimal.

Answer (score 0):

If a group of order $n$ has a subgroup of order $a$, then $a$ is a divisor of $n$.

A cyclic group of order $n$ has a (unique) subgroup of order $a$, for every divisor $a$ of $n$.

Thus the numbers $n$ for which the cyclic group of order $n$ has a subgroup of order $n$ are precisely the positive multiples of $a$.